# App unresponsive after dismissing MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController vc that is an MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate.  It instantiates MFMailComposeViewController, sets some of the fields and then presents it; no problem.
The UIViewController implements the didFinishWithResult method which dismisses MFMailComposeViewController; no problem.

Problem is; after the dismissal, the app becomes unresponsive.  I am testing on a phone, since the simulater creates an error pop-up.

Any ideas about why the app stops responding?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a simple workflow. Post your code?

Comment: you're checking `canSendMail` on MFMailComposeViewController, and setting `mailComposeDelegate`, not `delegate`, right?